# php - inner query not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting some data into `mysql` database from android app through `php` scripts.

I am sending two `POST` variables `$eventid` and `$phone`.
I need to get some data from another table using inner query using one variable value.

My `php` code looks like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO USER_EVENT
              (eventid,userid) 
        VALUES('$eventid',SELECT id FROM USER WHERE phone='".$phone."')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'Successfully registered';
}else{
    echo 'oops! Please try again!';
}
```

My code ending up in `else` clause. I am not sure what is going on here.

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to the Android tag?

Comment: @E-Kami Removed captain!! Do you see any solution to the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encapuslate the sub-query in round brackets

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO USER_EVENT
    (eventid,userid) 
    VALUES('$eventid', (SELECT id FROM USER WHERE phone='".$phone."'))";
//                     ^                                            ^
```

Usually the query-command should post this as notice/warning, you should check your logs.

By the way, your code is affective by sql injection, have a look at prepared statement and use parameters.

Comment: Yes would definitely use PDO in production. Just testing the app. Thanks